# Sencha 2.4 + cordova app failed to load on Android "TypeError: Result of expression 'b.onTargetTouchMove.bind' [undefined] is not a function. at..."

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I created a cordova app using sencha touch 2.4 framework and sencha cmd, It works on iOS and the majority of Android devices.
The problem appears on some old devices like Galaxy Ace and GT-B5510 for example.

It get stuck on the blue loading screen and throws this error:

```
09-12 23:43:41.386: E/Web Console(373): TypeError: Result of expression 'b.onTargetTouchMove.bind' [undefined] is not a function. at file:///android_asset/www/app.js:1
```

is there any solution for this problem or i just have to exclude these devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be the same issue as described and answered in the following post: 
[Sencha touch 2.4 appLoadingIndicator stack on android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845526/sencha-touch-2-4-apploadingindicator-stack-on-android-2-3/26546035#26546035).

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 5 not supported on old android devices :

please replace this

```
if (Ext.feature.has.Touch) {
 // bind handlers that are only invoked when the browser has touchevents
 me.onTargetTouchMove = me.onTargetTouchMove.bind(me);
 me.onTargetTouchEnd = me.onTargetTouchEnd.bind(me);
```

}
with

```
if (Ext.feature.has.Touch) {
// bind handlers that are only invoked when the browser has touchevents
me.onTargetTouchMove = Ext.Function.bind(me.onTargetTouchMove, me);
me.onTargetTouchEnd = Ext.Function.bind(me.onTargetTouchEnd, me);
}
```