# Sencha touch 2.4 appLoadingIndicator stack on android 2.3

Tags: android, extjs, touch, release

I have just downloaded sencha touch 2.4 and created a test android app. I am able to compile and run the app on android 4+ without problems. However, when I try to run it on android 2.3, the app doesn't go past the app loader indicator and I logged the process no errors are being displayed. Following is the code:

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Voice',

requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox'
],

views: [
    'Main'
],

icon: {
    '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
    '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
    '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
    '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
},

isIconPrecomposed: true,

startupImage: {
    '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
    '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
    '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
    '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
    '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
    '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
},

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Voice.view.Main'));
},

onUpdated: function() {
    Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Application Update",
        "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
        function(buttonId) {
            if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

});

and the main code:

```
Ext.define('Voice.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Video'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',

            scrollable: true,

            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            }]
        },
        {
            title: 'Get Started',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Getting Started'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'video',
                    url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                    posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

});

I think it must be a bug in the 2.4 sencha touch  release

Answer (score 6):

We also had the same issue and it seems that it is a bug introduced in Sencha Touch 2.4.
And the reason is the usage of bind() method which is a part of ECMAScript 5 not supported on android 2.3

So to fix it you can find the file touch\src\event\publisher\TouchGesture.js and replace the following lines

```
if (Ext.feature.has.Touch) {
    // bind handlers that are only invoked when the browser has touchevents
    me.onTargetTouchMove = me.onTargetTouchMove.bind(me);
    me.onTargetTouchEnd = me.onTargetTouchEnd.bind(me);
}
```

with these

```
if (Ext.feature.has.Touch) {
    // bind handlers that are only invoked when the browser has touchevents
    me.onTargetTouchMove = Ext.Function.bind(me.onTargetTouchMove, me);
    me.onTargetTouchEnd = Ext.Function.bind(me.onTargetTouchEnd, me);
}
```

This solution helped us to avoid the problem

Comment: Hello, thank you for your update. I tried other suggestions that I encountered online but they gave problem with other issues. So I opted to use sencha touch 2.3.1 which is performing quiet well. I will try your solutions this coming week and will update you accordingly. Thank you very much for your time and the feedback

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code! It worked like charm. I noticed one thing though, the font is a bit crispy and the border lines are not as smooth compared to version 2.3.1.. thumps up!!

Comment: Hi! Glad to see it helped you. If you are using fieldsets and default theme you may also notice that the label part has white background which is little annoying because it is not obvious where the field input element starts